# Unity2d buttons appears on the center of my phone screen . But i put them in the corner

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, position, 2d

In my unity2d project i added some gui buttons and arrange their position to corners while checking on 'game' window. But when i install my game on my phone, buttons changes position and appear on center of screen instead of corners.How can i solve this? If needed i can upload some ss.

[image: where it supposed to appears]

[image: where its appears]

[image: here is a example button of mine app]

Comment: Can you provide some code so everybody can understand your problem

Comment: As Hamza said we need some specifics (Code/Screenshots) but I would guess that your phones resolution is higher than your game window and the buttons need to be anchored to where you want them (Assuming that you are using Unity 5+ and the Canvas system)

Comment: okay guys i upload some screenshots

Comment: should i add a script for gui components ? i just arrange them with position coordinates not with a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change type of `UIScaleMode` to `Scale With Screen Size` in `Canvas Scaler` component. And then, change pivot of your buttons (if a button on the left bottom part of a screen, then pick LeftBottom and so on).

Comment: Thank you i will chekc it in a minute